# Serve Angular2 application

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing, node-static

using *lite-server* (Angular2 docs) my angular application runs perfectly but using *node-static* the manual navigation does not work.

For example if I manually write *localhost/404* using *lite-server* I can see my 404 page, but if I serve the application using *node-static* I get a blank page.

The console remains empty, so I really don't understand the cause.

This is my *node-static* server code:

```
var nodeStatic = require('node-static');
var file = new nodeStatic.Server('wwwroot');

require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        file.serve(request, response);
    }).resume();
}).listen(2035);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541532/is-angular-2s-router-broken-when-using-html5-routes/34543822#34543822

Answer (score 0):

You need either to use a server that redirects to the entry point or use `LocationStrategy` `HashLocationStrategy` instead of the default `PathLocationStrategy`.