# Angular2 routing / deep linking not working with Apache 404

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am following the Angular 2 routing examples.  Using the "lite" webserver I am able to navigate from the root and deep linking works, but using  Apache I can navigate from the root, but get 404 Not Found errors when following links direct to routes.

For example the following URL works against the "lite" webserver started on port 3000 by npm.

```
http://localhost:3000/crisis-center/2
```

But the next URL against Apache running on port 80 fails.

```
http://localhost/crisis-center/2
The requested URL /crisis-center/2 was not found on this server.
```

I did try a few .htaccess solutions recommended for similar Angular 1 issues but no luck.  If anyone has had Angular 2 routing and deep linking work on Apache please do let me know how you achieved that.

```
@RouteConfig([
{ // Crisis Center child route
path: '/crisis-center/...',
name: 'CrisisCenter',
component: CrisisCenterComponent,
useAsDefault: true
},

{path: '/heroes',   name: 'Heroes',     component: HeroListComponent},
{path: '/hero/:id', name: 'HeroDetail', component: HeroDetailComponent},
{path: '/disaster', name: 'Asteroid', redirectTo: ['CrisisCenter',  'CrisisDetail', {id:3}]}
])
```

Boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap}        from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {AppComponent}     from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

Comment: Does it work with https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/HashLocationStrategy-class.html ?

Comment: I did manage to get PathLocationStrategy working on Apache the following .htaccess  My previous attempts had failed because there were issues with AllowOverride and mod_rewrite module configuration.   

  RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html

Answer (score 59):

As the other answers don't really answer the question for if you want it to work with Apache. [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html) remains an option, but if you want it to work as is on Apache you need to do the following:

Create a new file `.htaccess` in the same location as your `index.html`. The following code will be inside:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /crisis-center/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

(Note that in the question the `<base href="/crises-center/">` inside the `index.html` should be identical to the RewriteBase)

Answer adapted from question+answer from  [Angular 2 routing and direct access to a specific route : how to configure Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198319/angular-2-routing-and-direct-access-to-a-specific-route-how-to-configure-apach)

Comment: Thanks.  I gave up on getting it to work with Apache, and did eventually get PathLocationStrategy working with nginx.  I believe most of the issues are on the Angular side, and adding the following seemed to fix them.      {path: '/**', redirectTo: ['Welcome']},

Comment: Provided HashLocationStrategy link currently doesn't work and there is a typo in the link name. There is `HasLocationStrategy` and should be `HashLocationStrategy` :). Currently working link: [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html)

Comment: `RewriteRule . /index.html [L]` did not work for me. But `RewriteRule . index.html [L]` does (without `/`).

Comment: It is not working for me.I am trying direct access to a specific route.and configured Apache.My base URL  <base href="/"> and .htaccess file      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase ///
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>  Please help me

Comment: Thank you @MA-Maddin, that solved it for me. Seems like the /index.html points to the servers root and doesn't recognize the RewriteBase. Any idea why?

Comment: thanks, it worked. but I still have 404 problem with https?

Answer (score 18):

For those who's running on Apache
use this **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you still get an error run those 2 commands:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for Angular 4+; exactly what I was looking for as it prevented the 404 on page refresh.

Comment: How can you add HTTPS-redirect in the above htaccess-file?

Comment: This worked like a charm... i will try to automate the creation of this file on ng build

Answer (score 5):

For angular4/angular in app.routes.module.ts include useHash as below,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, can i know the reason? When people search for angular4 routing, deep linking, this page is coming up in search results. So as explained i added a solution for angular4 as well. Stop being a coward and down voting with out a reason. It takes time for me to add this solution, i am just trying to help people same as me.

Comment: Thanks Yallam. Its working for me but i have one issue with this... my URL starts with "#/" how can i fix this. I don't want to see # in the url

Comment: It because you used the hash strategy @FaridAbbas. The by default strategy used by angular is Path Location Strategy which has many features like SEO friendly etc. Look at this article https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/

Comment: downvoted because no decent developer should ever use a hashtag without no partical reason in an angular2 app...

Comment: using hash is a hack around, only valid if you're building full-stack on the same proxy (when you have API serving on the same domain and you need separation)

Answer (score 4):

According to Rein Baarsma answer you have to create `.htaccess` file and put it in the same directory as your `index.html` on your Apache server. It might be for example `htdocs` directory, but this depends on your Apache configuration.

However I use different `.htaccess` file content and it works for me for all links/routes without necessity to specify rewrite base:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

It is a modification of code provided by Rein Baarsma.

My app is Angular 2+ (4.x.x) application based on angular-cli project. It hardly depends on direct URLs to addresses provided by Angular routing. Without `.htaccess` file above I got `404 not found` after clicking every direct URL link. Now with use of this `.htaccess` file everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with the ionic build and upload your site on hosting server then you need to add the **.htaccess** file on your root directory inside the **www** folder.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) / [R=302,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your server handle all routes back to index.html or use `HashLocationStrategy`

(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html)

Take a look at:

[Is Angular 2's Router broken when using HTML5 routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541532/is-angular-2s-router-broken-when-using-html5-routes)

Comment: Thanks, the stackoverflow link was useful, and there is a rather interesting issue on github about forcing front end developers to modify webserver configurations.  I predict a lot of time wasted when people develop on lightweight webservers and then try to deploy to the real world.

Comment: Yes I personally didn't like the fact that they made this mode the default mode without any other warning, but if you switch to HashLocationStrategy it should work without you having to go do anything in the backend server.

Comment: I have switched to HashLocationStrategy as that seems to have the least issues.

Answer (score 1):

Either in httpd.conf or in apache2.conf add the following:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

- Change "/var/www/html/" to your website location

And in .htaccess paste:

```
RewriteEngine On
      # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
      RewriteRule ^ - [L]
      # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This generator worked for me and my HostMonster account which uses Apapche HTTPD. The .htaccess file it generated worked out of the box:

https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator

```
# Generated with ngx-htaccess-generator v1.0.7
# https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  
  # Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  # Redirect all non-file routes to index.html
  RewriteRule ^(?!.*\.).*$ index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you, Julian Pömp!