# Angular 2 routing and direct access to a specific route : how to configure Apache?

Tags: apache, angular, angular2-routing

I developped a small Angular2 test app which, among other features, leverages routing.

It works fine as long as the user first accesses the home page, then navigates to sub pages.

If the user tries to directly access a subpage, I got a 404 if I do not configure the web server. This is perfectly normal as there is no "real page" corresponding to the route.

I tried to add the following configuration in apache 2.2 to handle HTML5 Push State:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/angular2-sens>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /angular2-sens
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /angular2-sens/index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

It makes things better as I no longer have a 404. However, I am "only" redirected to the home of the app and routing is not performed.

What should I do to correct this ?

My index.html page is :

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="simplegrid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sen.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.js"></script>
<!-- dev
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
-->

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
    System.config({
        map: {
            rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs' //or wherever you have it installed
        },
        packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
        }
    });
    System.import('app/boot')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <app>Chargement...</app>
</body>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
</html>
```

My app/boot.ts is :

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

import { enableProdMode } from 'angular2/core'; enableProdMode();

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

And, finally, my app component is :

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

import { enableProdMode } from 'angular2/core'; enableProdMode();

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

My app component, where the routing is configured, is :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {SensComponent} from './sens.component';
import {GroupesPolitiquesComponent} from './groupes-politiques.component';
import {SenVignetteComponent} from './sen-vignette.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
<h1>Application Angular 2 Relative aux Sénateurs (AA2RSen)</h1>
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['Senateurs']">Tous les Sénateurs en cours de mandat</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['GroupesPolitiques']">Groupes politiques</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
{path:'/senateurs', name: 'Senateurs', component: SensComponent},
{path:'/groupes',        name: 'GroupesPolitiques',       component: GroupesPolitiquesComponent},
{path:'/senateur/:matricule',      name: 'VignetteSenateur',   component: SenVignetteComponent}
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser especially the `<base href="">` tag.

Comment: Your redirection code helped me a lot. Fits perfect for my server I've used many `htaccess` files but none suggested using `RewriteBase `.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, so everything was fine excepted the fact that the dynamically generated base href was wrong.

Thanks to @günter-zöchbauer for pointing [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)

In my original code, it is generated from document.location :

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

If I switch to a static element :

```
<base href="/angular2-sens/"/>
```

It works. Of course, I will rather further analyse document.location in a "real" app.

Comment: I'm curious about how the generated URLs do differ before/after the change?

Comment: In the solution I indicate here, the base element is static and no longer generated. Or I did not understand your question ?

Comment: So it's not about the former didn't produce the correct `href` but that the dynamically added `<base>` tag didn't work at all?

Comment: If you want to set it dynamically use this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/34535256/217408

Comment: Another key point is that the <base href="..."/> element should be the *first* in the header, or you shall experience problems when directly accessing some URLs. Angular 2 tuto has been updated accordingly.