# Not able to deploy Angular 4 in production on live server

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, deployment, production

I have tried
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336358/6517383)
and can confirm that mod_rewrite is enabled on my hosting

And I have tried the following .htaccess configurations from various answers and sites but none helped.I'm not able to debug where the problem is.

[From the official site](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers):

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

From some gist

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And many others but all are giving 404 errors. Any way to debug it.
I'm using `ng build --prod` to make a dist then hosting on `dev.example.com` and trying to access `dev.example.com/home` which is available when accessed from `dev.example.com`
Could it be due to sub domain?

Comment: Are you able to access dev.example.com/index.html?

Comment: Yes and it redirects to `dev.example.com/home` due to my routing

Comment: @BlackMamba: Are you using both the configs? first in your `vHost` and other in `htaccess`?  Or you tried each in `htaccess` one at a time? The second one seems incorrect to me, although first one looks good to me, I will post what I use..

Comment: Tried each one at a time. Added some observation to my answer please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that it wasn't a subdomain issue. After trying a ton of `.htacess` files I was able to find  `RewriteBase`, add it to your base path like let's suppose your base path is `/dev/`
Add `Rewritebase /dev/` and don't forget to add `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you are facing problem with basepath please see this question [Angular 2 routing and direct access to a specific route : how to configure Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35198319/6517383)
and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36590784/6517383
Surely they will fix your deployment related issue on apache server

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
 RewriteEngine on
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Ahh, No success :(

Comment: @BlackMamba: you are testing under `.htaccess` right? you have the `AllowOverride All`  in your `vHost`?

Comment: Where  is it I'm on a shared hosting so I have limited access.I think it is enabled by default as the rest redirects are working fine.

Comment: Okay, if you are on a shared hosting then they must have added the config to override. You can check by doing something like: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/haha [NC, L]` just after `RewriteEngine On`, see if all your URLs are redirected to URL appended with `haha`? And I also wanted to know, if this is just happening in `production build` but `development` build works fine?

Comment: Giving 500 error in response. Haven't checked with a development build yet.I think this won't help as it is a server side issue

Comment: Okay, do one thing, replicate this on your local first.. create a virtual host with sever name : "dev.example.com" see if your config works in your machine..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170485/discussion-between-black-mamba-and-ashish-ranjan).

Answer (score 0):

I was missing httpd.conf, `AllowOverride All` over my directory

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```