# Angular 2 routing not working on page refresh with Apache

Tags: apache, angular, angular2-routing

Using Angular 2 RC 4 with the updated @angular/router, I got the route URLs to display in the browser using the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816025/angular2-routing-deep-linking-not-working-with-apache-404)

However, when I refresh or directly request a page with a route other than the default, it takes me to the default page (as if I requested index.html) rather than the routed page I want. How can I make the Angular 2 routes work correctly on a page refresh with Apache 2.4?

Routes and bootstrap:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboardTab', terminal: true },
{ path: 'dashboardTab', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'missionTab', component: MissionComponent, children: childRoutes }];

bootstrap(NavbarComponent, [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms(),   provideRouter(routes), {provide: Window, useValue: window}, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ResponsiveState, {provide: PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, useValue: RESPONSIVE_DIRECTIVES, multi: true}]).catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

base href in index.html:
    `<base href="/">`

Comment: Please show some code that demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish. Routes, `<base>` tag in `index.html`, `bootstrap(...)`, ...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Done. I didn't think adding code was relevant initially, though as the page refresh routing works when I run my code on lite-server.  It just doesn't seem to work on my Apache server.

Comment: `terminal: true` should be `pathMatch: 'full'` in the most recent version. If it runs with lite-server but not with Apache then your Apache is not configured to support HTML5 pushState. You can try switching to `HashLocationStrategy` to verify it. If this works, it's a server configuration issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically apache does not know anything about your angular application routes so it can't do much here.

**But**

Trick here is to get your apache server to serve `index.html` file even in page not found situations so that angular then can render the routes.

**Here are the steps**

1. Create a file called `.htaccess` inside of your angular applicaiton `src` folder, and copy the following code to it

```
  RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
      RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

2. You need to add this `.htaccess` file to the `assets` array in your `angular.json` so that angular will copy it to your `dist` folder when you do a production build.
3. finally after creating a production build if you copy your application to apache server everything should work fine, but in case if it does not you may want to do the last step

go to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` inside your server and modify

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To look like this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If that does not work probably you might not have enabled mod rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

See the deployment guide from angular team

https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 2):

Use the code in vhost of apache2:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/yourproject>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /yourproject
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /yourproject/index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

And use the code in index.html

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

this solves.

Comment: Thanks, This worked perfectly for me even without index.html changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set a handler for any URL that doesn't map to anything in your filesystem.

<Location "/my-app">FallbackResource /my-app/index.html

Add this line of code in your httpd.conf or in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf configuration file.

Your angular application routing will work on refresh.