# 404 error when refreshing Angular 2 page on AWS

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

If I go on any page by click on any `routerLink` then it is working fine but If I refresh page then it shows `404 error`. I came to know about `HashLocationStrategy` and so I need to use `#`. But I am looking for alternate solution.
Is there any way by which I can access page even when I refresh and that is without `HashLocationStrategy`?
I am using `Angular 2` and my website is hosted on `AWS S3`. What is the best solution - `HashLocationStrategy` or redirection rules?

Comment: you can do with apache configuration but on amazon s3 I suspect you can access apache conf else the better way is to implement HashLocationStrategy

Comment: @anshuVersatile, I don't want `#` that's why I am looking for alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html) you can write your custom redirection rules.

Just write your to redirect everything to the index.html page except /api or whatever is your API endpoint.

Comment: As per your opinion, what is the best solution ? `HashLocationStrategy` or redirection rules ?

Comment: HashLocationStrategy  obviously cause amazon s3 is not permenant solution and if you shift to shared hosting or subdomain then you will need HashLocationStrategy  again

Answer (score 0):

[Angular2 routing / deep linking not working with Apache 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816025/angular2-routing-deep-linking-not-working-with-apache-404)

the above link will help you for configure server to redirecting to specific location and as @Sakuto suggested use amazon redirection rules

Comment: As per your opinion, what is the best solution ? `HashLocationStrategy` or redirection rules ?