# Angular 2 Routing configuration in liberty Websphere server

Tags: angular2-routing, websphere-liberty

My angular 2 app runs fine on my local node server. However when the dist/prod contents are deployed to a server (to be precise websphere liberty server) The url just works fine for once. When I try to reload it, it gives me File not found exception. Also the deep routes for e.g http://localhost:5555/myapp/route1/somefeature/extra doesn't work and throws the same exception.

Just to confirm:

1. I am using proper basehref (for e.g '/myproduct/')
2. The server.xml contains proper contextpath ('/myproduct/')
3. Thus the url http://someserver:8080/myproduct/myapp runs fine but when refreshed or deep routes are hit, it throws file not found exception

I have gone through this post [Angular2 routing / deep linking not working with Apache 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816025/angular2-routing-deep-linking-not-working-with-apache-404) and need the similar kind of settings in my server.xml (for liberty websphere server)

Since I do not want to go back to include old implementation of hash(#) urls, Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: we moved to express server to serve my app. Even though on express we have to write this special line to redirect all request to index.html.
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'prod')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'prod') + '/index.html');
});`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try in web.xml?

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: thanks for the input. However just an update.. I moved to express server :)

Comment: This solution worked for me.
In my case, my angular app is packaged in ear file and its routing was not working. The only route working was ''.
After adding <error-page> in web.xml in my Angular app, all routes started working. Thank you very much.