# Auth0 callback only works in development for my Angular 2 (4) app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, auth0

When I test my Angular 4 login with Auth0 in development mode with `localhost:4000/callback` as `redirectUri` for my `auth0.WebAuth` it works fine.

However, when I go to production, with `redirectUri = https://example.com/my/app/callback` then I get the following error from the console log

`GET https://example.com/my/app/callback 404 (Not Found)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and googling I have landed on this being a server issue for routing and deep linking. Please see this stackoverflow for details:

[Angular2 routing / deep linking not working with Apache 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816025/angular2-routing-deep-linking-not-working-with-apache-404)