# angular Deployment issue with tomcat

Tags: angular, typescript, tomcat, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular 6 my am some getting some issue while deploy application on tomcat

***i have Base href = /login/***

when i go to any page like you see below forget routerlink it work but when i refresh or directly  open ***http:localhost:8088/login/forget***  it will not display this page its showing serve issue  like 2 image

[image]

***This is After reload the page***

[image]
**In Development mode everything working fine without any error**

***Step that i use to deploy aplication***

1. 1.ng build --prod --base-href /login/
2. copy dist folder files
3. go Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ and create login folder
4. paste all dist folder file into tomcat login folder like below you can see
5. start tomcat sever

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 routing / deep linking not working with Apache 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816025/angular2-routing-deep-linking-not-working-with-apache-404)

Comment: @BearNithi i am not talking about image issue i have issue when u reload page it not working

Comment: @FatemeFazli can you please help me

Comment: based on link above did you add .htaccess file?

Comment: @FatemeFazli i tryed but its does not work

Answer (score 1):

I am using this in “app.module.ts” (check this link where I got some help: "https://medium.com/tinywave/angular-6-404-error-during-refresh-after-deployed-8cec7140b584")

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy  } from '@angular/common';

providers: [
            {provide : LocationStrategy , useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
           ],
```

After that import, the site works well and call the spring services, but, I have a reload for CRUD in the same page and there is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy all these files and paste them in /angular folder under /webapps folder in tomcat.

Once copied, fire up the server and visit localhost:8080/angular/index.html and our bikes app should be seen running.

=====OR=======

Open the index.html file, replace the base-href=”/angular/” with base-href=”.” and restart the tomcat and access the url.

Or

For each of the script tag, in src tag add “angular/”
e.g.

All doing any of the change suggested, refresh the page in browser. Error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

The application deep links will not work without the redirect rule on the server. All the deep links have to redirect to the application `index.html` by the server.

To setup the tomcat to redirect any deep links -

1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml
2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config

**1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml**

Edit the ~/conf/server.xml to add the below Valve inside the Host section as below –

```
...
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

...
      </Host>
...
```

**2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config**

Create directory structure – ~/conf/Catalina/localhost/ and create the rewrite.config file inside it with the below content –

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/login/(.*) /login/index.html
```

After setting this up restart the tomcat server and you can hit the deep links of the application which will route to the correct components inside the angular application.

You can refer to [this post](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/) for more details.