# Angular2 routing how to go to base directory

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying the tutorial Angular2 tutorial, but it doesn't seem to understand the routes after a refresh.
The source code can be found on https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/tutorial/ts/plnkr.html

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['Heroes']">Heroes</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [HeroService]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/heroes', name: 'Heroes', component: HeroesComponent},
  {path: '/detail/:id', name: 'HeroDetail', component: HeroDetailComponent}
])
```

What it does is that it replaces the base `/` by `/dashboard` but when you refresh the page, I want it to understand that `/dashboard` === `/dashboard` and not `/`, because it thinks that it's the base directory, so the links shows `/dashboard/dashboard` and the ts are failing to load as they are included in relative way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a server that is able to cope with HTML5 pushState
or change the location strategy from `PathLocationStrategy` to `HashLocationStrategy` by adding the follogin to your `bootstrap()`

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent[
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  /* after ROUTER_PROVIDERS */
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}). 
]);
```

See also [Is Angular 2's Router broken when using HTML5 routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541532/is-angular-2s-router-broken-when-using-html5-routes/34543822#34543822)

Comment: Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer. I didn't solve my problem yet, but it's not related to Angular, but Go, so I will reformulate my question.

Comment: Your server needs to redirect all requests to index.html as also explained  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser